# Footnotes in an excel pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to display my SQL query result as an excel pivot table. But I could not figure out how to display the footnotes (which is another columns in the result set) on the pivot table. The trouble is excel tries to aggregate every data point in the data fields area, including textual data.

Anybody had any success with this? The notes that I want to display is short, only 1-2 characacters, so showing along with the actual data is perfectly acceptable.

Please note that cell comments does not work as they do not move as the user tweaks the rows and columns (but, a script that automatically moves the comments would also be OK)

Thanks a lot

Kemal

Answer (score 1):

Pivot tables are exclusively for the *aggregation* of tabular data. Since your footnotes are not aggregate-able (strings), they won't appear in the pivot. So I'd say you are out of luck.

The way I would handle this is to aggregate the data in SQL and bring in the results along with the footnotes as a table. Of course, this is contingent upon the flexibility you want to have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I automatically generate the xlsx file for the user and all they need is to play with the columns and rows, do filtering, etc. The data that is fetched from excel already have a column for the footnotes.